# How to handle a different types of exception in a one place?

Tags: java, playframework

I'm using `play 2.8.x framework` and I have the following controller:

```
public class HomeController extends Controller {
    public Result show(Http.Request request) throws MyException {
        ...
        return ok("some_data");
    }
}
```

and I want to do something like in a `Spring framework` for handling exceptions:

```
// It is from the Spring web framework
@ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public ExplainExceptionDTO handleMyException() {
    ...
    return explain;
}
```

Can I do something like this in the `play 2.8.x framework`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This explains it pretty well: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaErrorHandling

```
@Singleton
public class ErrorHandler implements HttpErrorHandler {
  public CompletionStage<Result> onClientError(
      RequestHeader request, int statusCode, String message) {
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(
        Results.status(statusCode, "A client error occurred: " + message));
  }

  public CompletionStage<Result> onServerError(RequestHeader request, Throwable exception) {
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(
        Results.internalServerError("A server error occurred: " + exception.getMessage()));
  }
}
```

The method you are interested in is `onServerError`. So instead of returning the default internalServerError check the Throwable type, if it's your exception return `badRequest()`, you can even provide the template if you want.